# Magento: Jquery not working however will work in console

Tags: jquery, magento-1.5

I am trying to get a simple jQuery script to work on my magento product page. However after adding the jQuery script to the XML and thus magento being able to read and add the jQuery script in the header... the script still does not work. I then tried putting the script into the chrome console and it worked fine.

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("#ship").show();
    $j("#details").hide();
    $j("#sizing").hide();
    $j(".ship").css("text-decoration","underline");

    $j(".ship").click(function(){
        $j(".ship").css("text-decoration","underline");
        $j(".details").css("text-decoration","none");
        $j(".sizing").css("text-decoration","none");
        $j("#ship").show();
        $j("#details").hide();
        $j("#sizing").hide();
    });

    $j(".details").click(function(){
        $j(".ship").css("text-decoration","none");
        $j(".details").css("text-decoration","underline");
        $j(".sizing").css("text-decoration","none");
        $j("#ship").hide();
        $j("#details").show();
        $j("#sizing").hide();
    });

    $j(".sizing").click(function(){
        $j(".ship").css("text-decoration","none");
        $j(".details").css("text-decoration","none");
        $j(".sizing").css("text-decoration","underline");
        $j("#ship").hide();
        $j("#details").hide();
        $j("#sizing").show();
    });

});
```

Comment: Have you set jQuery to noconflict mode?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Jquery.noConflict() function. it will solve the issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```